# if attribute is xyz, show (pre-defined) text in product view

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to show a pre-defined text in product view for some special products. These products all have a special value for an attribute.

I need a solution to show tgis text, when the attribute has this special value.

Another solution could be to show this text if a checkbox (an attribute?) is checked.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you need.

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'attribute_code', $store_id);

if ($attribute == "needed value")
{
    echo "my pre defined text";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very fast answer. I think I got it. For 'attribute_code' I use the attribute which should have the special value to show the text.

But where do I define the needed value?

Comment: i updated my answer. not sure i understand. you want something like this?

Comment: To put the "needed value" in the if statement.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.

I tried

<?php $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
            $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'kfz_batterie_typ', $store_id);
                if ($attribute == "starter")
                {
                    echo "my pre defined text";
                };?>

'kfz_batterie_typ' is the attribute, 'starter' is the needed value.

Comment: Some html code for testing worked in this file. So I know that it is the right one.

Comment: hm.. let me test my self a moment.

Comment: it works fine for me. i used sku as attribute code. so try the code with another attribute than `kfz_batterie_typ`. To see if there is a problem with your custom attribute... Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'sku', $store_id); if ($attribute == "mysku")

Comment: Oh yes, it works. I need to check my attribute data.

Thanks so much for your help at this day time!

Comment: Could it be that it doesn't work with option lists? When I use an attribute with a textfield - it works. But not with option lists.

Hm...

Comment: OK, it works. I need to use the option_id. I found it in the database in the table 'eav_attribute_option_value'.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is it also possible to show a static cms block? In this case it would be possible to have editable text which is not hard coded.

Comment: yes i suppose you can add everything you want... For a static block you can use something like `echo $this->getChildHtml('my_static_block')`. Please check my answer as corrent to help other people in this site. It's not that difficult...ok?

Comment: as i see in your profile you never mark questions as correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the attribute value ,

just echo  $_product->getRefillProduct()  ; // attribute id is refill_product

fore more detail click on http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/